# Should I be concerned about the following URLs that were tried to open on my webpage?

Tags: web-application, injection, path-injection

I don't know if this is some injection attempt or a weird bot or what ever. An IP opened several pages within my Drupal 7 website with the appendix

```
http://domain.com/some/url/$tags.get(%22pixelLink%22)
```

I didn't find anything on Google. What does `$tags.get(%22pixelLink%22)` mean? Should I prevent this and if so, how?

Comment: %22 is ", so this is $tags.get("pixelLink"). Do you have variables called `tags` on Drupal, and does `pixelLink` correspond to any content on your website?

Comment: It could be that it's a Web crawler attempting to get content for a specific topic, but that crawler somehow had a programming error that prevented part of the URL it visited from being properly filled?

Comment: i dont, no. i believe its a crawler also, thanks Steve

Comment: Could it a be a bad <a> HTML tag? More like: <a href="$tags.get(...)">something</a>, rather than the <a href="javascript:$tags.get(...)"> ?

Comment: the referer is random, i didnt find any of those links so i guess not